# Can I use `type` to check whether an arbitrary name is a valid command name?

Tags: shell, posix, portability

The bash built-in `type` can be used for this purpose by checking its exit status:

```
Exit Status:
Returns success if all of the NAMEs are found; fails if any are not found.
```

How portable is it? The POSIX spec is a little bit less clear regarding the exit status of `type`:

```
EXIT STATUS    
    The following exit values shall be returned:    
     0 Successful completion.
    >0 An error occurred.
```

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/type.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The type utility shall indicate how each argument would be interpreted if
> used as a command name.
>
> (…)
>
> The following exit values shall be returned:
>
> `0`  Successful completion.
> `>0`  An error occurred.

“Successful completion” means that the argument can be interpreted as a command name, in which case command lookup would succeed. An error means that the argument could not be interpreted as a command name, in which case command lookup would fail.

The return status of `type` is a fully POSIX-portable way of checking whether a command name is valid, or as close as it can get. There are older systems where `type` returns 0 on invalid commands (such as OSF1 V3, but I think OSF1 V4 is POSIX-compliant, at least when the shell environment is in POSIX mode (`BIN_SH=xpg4`)), but POSIX-compliant systems return 0 only upon success.

What you cannot rely on with `type` is the output format, or whether the output will be on stdout or stderr.

It is impossible to have a guarantee that the outcome of `type` matches what happens if you try to actually run the program. An executable may have been added or removed in the meantime, or may fail to load because the file is invalid or because there isn't enough memory. But if you're just looking to see if a command exists and not concerned about edge cases, `if type somecommand >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; …` is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, using the POSIX spec as a guide there really is no way to tell what is considered an error. So there's no way to guarantee that a zero exit code means the operand is a valid name exists, much less that it is a command.

It looks like standard output is not much help either (my emphasis):

> The standard output of type contains information about each operand in an **unspecified format**. The information provided **typically** identifies the operand as a shell built-in, function, alias, or keyword, and where applicable, may display the operand's pathname.

Looks like you'll have to use some heuristic, for example based on the shell you're using.